# MIME-encoded file creation in Java

Tags: java, mime

Just for learning purpose I want to create MIME type file. Is there any java api is available to create file? I want to embed pkcs7 response in to this file.

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="=_1_1440399813_23993"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

This is a MIME-formatted message.  If you see this text it means that your
E-mail software does not support MIME-formatted messages.

--=_1_1440399813_23993
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=hello.pdf
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

MMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDA1MzUwIDAwMDAwIG4g
CnRyYWlsZXIKPDwvU2l6ZSAxNC9Sb290IDEyIDAgUgovSW5mbyAxMyAwIFIKL0lEIFsgPDZCQjND
QzhCOTkyNDMxMkIxMEZDOUI1MjM3NEQzODYyPgo8NkJCM0NDOEI5OTI0MzEyQjEwRkM5QjUyMzc0
RDM4NjI+IF0KL0RvY0NoZWNrc3VtIC9FNUJGNDQ1NENFRUY4RDk0RjNGRDM4NUU5NTFEOERBNAo+
PgpzdGFydHhyZWYKNTUyNQolJUVPRgo=

--=_1_1440399813_23993
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=hello.pdf.p7s
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

Lxbtj3FFg7Ss7fxsq/pSBHYBTLlDZ9K1
mmMmCygSi6+JMfbqj/vu50L79qtq3TgfMXh8GIOWqpiIh6c4/U29T6yZIBFktqiS1vRWiONM9OCx
WlrP70y9XePc/L+HyBeuUjFNCnSsxVO1atgYgLI4GdXu2jc1wTonuQVmNbsTtQ2r27SiM9eTkJYW
jrURoe5lBMTQ6rxGZWdB8bnQXjvQhmOqoDmXJ161MZ/jxbTEwHclDuKggOG29nEfZe/ybq25Fyu8
k01tvUXJJ1EanVZQwFVaoqOmR6W1/HGSxB3S7A==

--=_1_1440399813_23993--
```

Is there any api availabe to create this type of file? Can i give any extension for this file? I am very new in this area.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the Java Mail API for this. (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index-141777.html)

But actually my experience is that this API is no fun to use and as long as you just want to encode several files to one MIME message it might be easier to encode it yourself.

Some frameworks like Spring (org.springframework.mail.*) build wrappers around Java Mail, that make it easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge there is no ready API for this.

Keep in mind that MIME multipart encoding is just plain text. So you can format this in the regular `StringBuilder`.

The only somewhat difficult part may be base64 encoding, but for that there is a ready class: [Base64](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html).

You could easily have a function, which takes an array of array of bytes and returns the formatted string, or you could do a class to which you keep `addData`-ing and then finally get the result.

It really depends upon your design what you want to do.